# MATLAB Array comparisons

Tags: matlab

I am just learning MATLAB for the first time.

I am reading some code trying to understand it. I believe I have two arrays below called pdw_raw & pdw_factors which contains a list of dates. The line that is causing me most confusion is the last line in the code below. The only way I can seem to make sense of this line is that every element in pdw_raw is being check against the max date of pdw_factors - is this correct?

Find the MATLAB syntax hard to understand at the moment.

```
%first retrieve the relevant dates;
sql_statement   = ['select distinct pricedatew from D_RAWRETS order by pricedatew'];
cursor          = exec(QES_DB, sql_statement);
cursor          = fetch(cursor);
pdw_raw         = datenum(cursor.data);
pdw_raw         = pdw_raw(1:end-1, 1);

sql_statement   = ['select distinct pricedatew from D_FACTORS order by pricedatew'];
cursor          = exec(QES_DB, sql_statement);
cursor          = fetch(cursor);
pdw_factors     = datenum(cursor.data);

missing_dates   = pdw_raw(pdw_raw > max(pdw_factors));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.

`pdw_raw > max(pdw_factors)` creates an array of logicals that is true for elements of `pdw_raw` that are bigger than the largest `pdw_factors` elements, and false otherwise.

`pdw_raw(pdw_raw > max(pdw_factors));` uses [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) to extract only the elements for which `pdw_raw > max(pdw_factors)` is true.

Comment: +1, @mHelpMe: Note that `max` returns a vector if the input argument is a 2D-matrix. I.e. it returns the maximum value of each column, not the overall maximum as a single number.

Comment: @RobertP. true, but in this case `pwd_factors` comes from a sql query that only selects a single column so it is safe to assume that it is a vector.

Comment: I know =) It was just a small reminder to OP, as it is not intuitive and could easily cause problems in other situations.